# If $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$, prove $\frac{a}{a+bc}+\frac{b}{b+ca}+\frac{\sqrt{abc}}{a+ba}\le 1+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$, then prove

$$\frac{a}{a+bc}+\frac{b}{b+ca}+\frac{\sqrt{abc}}{a+ba}\le 1+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Comment: are you sure ,this inequation to be correct?

Comment: This can't be correct. If we let $b=0.5,c=0.5-a$ then LHS tends to infinity as $a$ tends to zero. The third term is roughly a constant times $1/\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: In particular, for $a=0.001$, LHS is over $11$ (according to Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: is this from MathLinks?

Comment: I think  LHS is $\dfrac{a}{a+bc}+\dfrac{b}{b+ca}+\dfrac{\sqrt{abc}}{c+ab}$

Comment: yes in the last sumand is a typo

Comment: can you correct your problem please?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner http://matkafasi.com/6260/a-b-c-pozitif-reel-sayilar-olsun-%24a-b-c-1%24-ise note:it is a question from Olympiad

Answer (score 1):

HINT: set $a=xy,b=yz,c=zx$ and after this use the $\tan(\alpha/2)$ etc substitution4}
after simplification we get 
$$\frac{1}{1+z^2}+ \frac {1}{1+x^2}+\frac {y}{1+y^2}\le 1+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
now set $$x=\tan(\alpha/2),y=\tan(\beta/2),z=\tan(\gamma/2)$$
after simplification we get
$$\cos(\gamma)+\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)\le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the tangent half angle part?

Comment: with this we have worked in our Math circle in Leipzig